# Creating Xamarin Forms control from existing controls

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, controls, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms there is a `TimePicker` control. I can instantiate the control from my xaml code and bind the Time property to a property on my view model.

I would like to create a similar control for selecting days of the week ("Monday", "Tuesday", etc). Let's call it `DaysOfWeekPicker`. `DaysOfWeekPicker` should allow the user to select zero, one or multiple (up to 7) days. This is different to the standard `Picker` which only allows exactly one item to be selected.

I've found tutorials which explain how to create custom controls with native renderers defined for each platform. However, as a first pass, I would be happy to implement `DaysOfWeekPicker` using just the other controls that already exist in Xamarin Forms such as buttons and labels. Is there a way I can do this without creating new renderers for each platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a ContentView to your project

[image: Xamarin Add ContentView]

Your ContentView can have a XAML file which you can use to define its looks or you can do that in the code behind

Take a look at [Bindable Properties](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/data_binding_basics/) (especially about property change events) and [Behaviors](http://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin.forms/) and investigate how they work. You will likely need to write some code to define how your control works, moves, responds, validates etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried this, but it not quite doing what I want. It is showing all of the days in my main view where I placed the `<DaysOfWeekPicker>` element. Is there some way I can make it act more like the `TimePicker` which pops up the selection dialogue only when it is pressed?

Comment: so... yes all of that is possible and you'll need to implement it yourself. Take a look at BindableProperty: you can create a bool property on your new ContentView that indicates if it's expanded or collapsed, hook on the property changed handler and change the looks of your control as needed

Comment: I will read up on Bindable properties and behaviours. Thanks.